# how to set stride to zero when using tf.layers.conv2d

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

is there a way that I can turn off stride in tensor flow when using: tf.layers.conv2d()? According to the docs, the default is (1,1) but when I try to change this to (0,0) I get an error telling me that it has to be a positive number.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A unity stride is the same as not having a stride (turning it off), as its the normal way a convolution works.

As the stride is the amount of pixels the sliding window moves, one is the minimum value, and zero would not be valid as then the sliding window wouldn't move at all.